# unable to access my rails using Public IP of my Ubuntu server in a browser

Tags: ubuntu, ruby, rails

I have a Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-63-generic x86_64) server and my public IP is something like 183.xx.xxx.xx (curl -4 icanhazip.com).I have started my rails app using the command:

```
rails s -b0.0.0.0 -p3002
```

and puma server has started successfully

```
    => Booting Puma
    => Rails 5.0.3 application starting in development on http://localhost:3002
    => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
    Puma starting in single mode...
    * Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.4.0-p0), codename: Private Caller
    * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
    * Environment: development
    * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3002
    Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

I tried to access my app in the browser using:

```
 http://183.xx.xxx.xx:3002
```

I am getting

```
This site can’t be reached
172.xx.xxx.xx took too long to respond.
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Any help is highly Appreciate.Thanks in Advance!

**EDIT 1**

**netstat -plnt**

```
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:45109           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3002            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25689/0.0.0.0:3002)
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

A process is running with a pid 25689

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but your command starts with port 3002; however, the output shows the server is listening on port 3000. Could this be the issue?

Comment: @schaiba, Thanks for the quick response.I apologize for the typo and  I have edited  it .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would check iptables. Executing `iptables -L` ou should see something like:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere    anywhere   tcp dpt:3002 ctstate NEW
```

which means that your firewall allows connection to that port. If you don't, try adding a rule to access to that port with this command:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3002 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: @Luiz , thanks you for your response.I have added running ports list in the edit.I have also  adding the rule sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3002 -j ACCEPT.But i am still unable to access my app in browser

Comment: If you want to completely discard firewall problems you can try to disable firewall with 'sudo iptables -F' and trying again. To restore the firewall, you should just reboot your server. It is very important restoring firewall!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the browser is on the same machine as the server, you're better off using this URL instead:

`http://127.0.0.1:3002`

Accessing your own public IP is usually problematic, since you're generally relying on a fairly complex route. `127.0.0.1` is another name for `localhost` and is the standard way for connecting to servers on the same machine.

Sometimes servers expect to be accessed by domain name instead. It doesn't look like this is an issue for you, but if you ever go down that route, just add the following line to your `/etc/hosts` file:

`127.0.0.1       your.public.domain.name`

Finally, in case you're confused by the appearance of `0.0.0.0` in your netstat table, note that the table lists what interface servers are **listening** on. Some servers are listening to **all** interfaces (`0.0.0.0`) while others are only listening to the local interface (`127.0.0.1`).